# Why does adding a std::cout statement stop a segmentation fault from occuring?

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, tensor

I am implementing a class, `Tensor`, to implement functionality for a multidimensional array stored contiguously in memory. I am currently trying to test the functionality against a 3 dimensional vector, declared as `mirror` in the code below.

With the `std::cout` statement in the `Tensor::resize()` function commented out the code gives a segmentation fault, this occurs when `i=2`, `j=2`, `k=7` in the nested loop. Printing out `mirror[i].size()` at this point yields an obviously incorrect value which changes from run to run.

When the aformentioned `std::cout` statement in `Tensor::resize()` function is not commented out, the pointer value of `data` is printed to memory and the program executes without a failure. Can I get any pointers as to what may be causing this ususual behaviour?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename Ty, size_t N>
class Tensor
{
private:
    Ty *data;
    size_t *offset;
public:
    Tensor() :
        data(nullptr), offset((size_t*)malloc((N+1)*sizeof(size_t)))
    {}
    Tensor(Ty *data, size_t *offset) :
        data(data), offset(offset)
    {}

    Tensor<Ty, N-1> operator[] (size_t i)
    {
        return Tensor<Ty, N-1>(&data[i*offset[N-1]], offset);
    }

    void resize(size_t* size)
    { 
        offset[0] = 1;
        for (size_t i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
        {
            offset[i] = offset[i-1]*size[N-i];
        }
        data = (Ty*)realloc(data, offset[N]);
        //std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename Ty>
class Tensor<Ty, 1>
{
private:
    Ty *data;
    size_t len;
public:
    Tensor() :
        data(nullptr), len(0)
    {}
    Tensor(Ty *data, size_t *offset) :
        data(data), len(offset[1])
    {}

    Ty &operator[](size_t i)
    {
        return data[i];
    }

    void resize(size_t* size)
    {
        len = size[0];
        data = (Ty*)realloc(data, len);
    }
};

int main() {
    Tensor<double, 3> matrix;
    size_t size[3] = {5,4,10};
    matrix.resize(size);

    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> mirror(5, std::vector<std::vector<double>>(4, std::vector<double>(10) ) );
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
            {
                double num = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
                mirror[i][j][k] = 0.0;
                matrix[i][j][k] = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You likely have UB somewhere. Turn up your warnings and run through asan, ubsan, and masan

Comment: The seg-fault is probably caused by Undefine Behaviour and adding or removing any code can make the program appear to work.  This does not mean the UB has been removed only hidden temporarily.

Comment: UB means *anything* can happen ; https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: Couldn't your `Tensor` class simply wrap a `std::vector`, instead of your code trying to do what `std::vector` does, and without error?

Comment: you should read this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three. Make sure to read till the end, the rule of 0 is your friend

Comment: *When the aformentioned std::cout statement in Tensor::resize() function is not commented out* -- I took your code as written, compiled it using Visual Studio 2019, ran the debug version, and got a memory exception, regardless of whether `cout` is there or not.  So finagling with the `cout` statement is not a fix for the issue, if that's what you were hoping for.  If anything, remove the `std::cout` and fix the code.  The last thing you want are superfluous, do nothing lines of code masking the bug.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie how would I implement the operator[] function without having to copy the contents of the vector then?

Comment: I suggest you do more debugging, as Visual Studio detects you are stomping all over memory with the code you have now.  Maybe put in some more output statements to verify if `data` is pointing to the correct place?  And also, why not start out with 2 dimensions instead of 3?  If it doesn't work for 2, you know it will not work for 3.  Not only that, you would have a much better chance of fixing the issue with a smaller number of dimensions.

Comment: As a matter of fact, it is `matrix[i][j][k] = 0.0;` that is causing the issue.  Since supposedly you wrote this code, you should be able to debug what you are doing in that recursive template call to cause the memory overwrite.  That's the issue when writing template code -- you better know how to debug it if issues like this come along.  Also and as an aside to this, you didn't check if `malloc` or `realloc` return NULL.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the help, I managed to narrow it down to the realloc statement allocating `offset[N]` bytes instead of `offset[N]*sizeof(double)` bytes.